# Golang Redis Sentinel client

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm adding Redis support to an open-source project written in Go. The goal is to support all Redis topologies: server, cluster, sentinel.

I browsed Go clients listed in *redis.io/clients*, and it seems that *github.com/go-redis/redis* project is a viable option.

My main concern is the *NewSentinelClient()* method accepts a single sentinel address.
According to the Guidelines for Redis clients (*redis.io/topics/sentinel-clients#guidelines-for-redis-clients-with-support-for-redis-sentinel*), "the client should iterate the list of Sentinel addresses. "

How can *SentinelClient* iterate through the rest of sentinel instances, if it only has one sentinel address?

Do I miss something?

On the same topic, could someone recommend another Go Redis client that might be suitable for this scenario?

Comment: AFAIK, you should connect to the master node. go-redis is a good choice, the problem you are facing is with your redis-sentinel not with your client.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NewFailoverClient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#NewFailoverClient) if you have multiple sentinels.

```golang
rdb := redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions{
    MasterName: "mymaster",
    SentinelAddrs: []string{
        "sentinel_1:26379",
        "sentinel_2:26379",
        "sentinel_3:26379",
    },
})
```